# Need Help modifying Chart.js mouse-over tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following jQuery plugin on my site:
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

I have a line chart with 20 lines on it, 15 of which are hidden by default using the following:

```
for (var i = 5; i < $d.datasets.length; i++) {  //5 = starting dataset so we aren't hiding 'TM' data
    $d.datasets[i].strokeColor = "rgba(0,0,255,0)";
    $d.datasets[i].pointColor = "rgba(0,0,255,0)";
}
```

This works great for hiding the lines and I can give the user the ability to toggle any of the lines on/off with some clickable div's and a lil jQuery, bing bang boom, no prob!

There's a problem... LOL!

The tool-tip still shows all the data for a given point on the line but shows all the "hidden" values as white squares.

How can I modify the '**chart.min.js**' code to:

```
//Psuedo - if the alpha value of the point color is 0, don't use this data
if(pointColor.a == 0) return;
```

Or some such thing so that the value is not included in the tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, I found it! :D

Search for this (x3):

```
e.each(t.datasets,function(i){var s={label:i.label||null
```

Replace with this (x3):

```
e.each(t.datasets, function (i) { if (i.strokeColor.split(',')[3].replace(')', '') == 0) return; var s = { label: i.label || null
```

If you have lines hiding by setting the alpha value of the stroke color to 0, this will remove those data points from the mouse-over menu.  As soon as you turn the alpha back on, the items reappear in the tooltip.